# Does Google Cloud ML support GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I'm testing Google Cloud ML for speeding up my ML model using Tensorflow.

Unfortunately, it seems like Google Cloud ML is extremely slow. My Mainstream-Level PC is at least 10x faster than Google Cloud ML.

I doubt it uses GPU, so I did a test. I modified a sample [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/38fb21771da3fe6fae661c343f2ece8eaba1c8c5/mnist/trainable/trainer/task.py) to force using GPU.

```
diff --git a/mnist/trainable/trainer/task.py b/mnist/trainable/trainer/task.py
index 9acb349..a64a11d 100644
--- a/mnist/trainable/trainer/task.py
+++ b/mnist/trainable/trainer/task.py
@@ -131,11 +131,12 @@ def run_training():
     images_placeholder, labels_placeholder = placeholder_inputs(
     FLAGS.batch_size)

-    # Build a Graph that computes predictions from the inference model.
-    logits = mnist.inference(images_placeholder, FLAGS.hidden1, FLAGS.hidden2)
+    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
+      # Build a Graph that computes predictions from the inference model.
+      logits = mnist.inference(images_placeholder, FLAGS.hidden1, FLAGS.hidden2)

-    # Add to the Graph the Ops for loss calculation.
-    loss = mnist.loss(logits, labels_placeholder)
+      # Add to the Graph the Ops for loss calculation.
+      loss = mnist.loss(logits, labels_placeholder)

     # Add to the Graph the Ops that calculate and apply gradients.
     train_op = mnist.training(loss, FLAGS.learning_rate)
```

This training code works at my PC (`gcloud beta ml local train ...`) but not in cloud. It gives errors like this:

```
 "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 239, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 235, in main
    run_training()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 177, in run_training
    sess.run(init)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'softmax_linear/biases': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no devices matching that specification are registered in this process; available devices: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices:
ApplyGradientDescent: CPU
Identity: CPU
Assign: CPU
Variable: CPU
     [[Node: softmax_linear/biases = Variable[container="", dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[10], shared_name="", _device="/device:GPU:0"]()]]
```

Does Google Cloud ML support GPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPUs are now in Beta and all Cloud ML customers have access.

Here are the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-gpus) for using GPUs with Cloud ML.

Comment: any luck getting them to work? When I try to run my job specifying a GPU, the job just sits in the queue...

```
gcloud beta ml jobs submit training gpu_job_basic_gpu \
--package-path=train \
--staging-bucket="${STAGING_BUCKET}" \
--module-name=train.1-multiply \
--region=us-central1 \
--scale-tier=BASIC_GPU
```

Comment: Try region us-east1.

Comment: wow that worked. What gave you the intuition to try east when the docs clearly say central should work?

Comment: I work for Google and am responsible for GPUs in Cloud ML. Due to GPU demand we had move out of us-central1. The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-gpus) have been updated to reflect that.

Comment: thanks for the update, running my job out of east now.